# Display product weight in shopify with decimal places. ( ex. 0.25)

Tags: shopify, liquid

so currently working on a shopify website and for one of my products the weight of it is 0.25. But when i try to display this on the page i end up with only 0.2. I didnt write this code as another developer did and im still trying to learn how to use shopify.

```
{% if product.variants.first.weight != 0 %}
                            <p>
                               {{ product.variants.first.weight | weight_with_unit }}
                                          
                               {% comment %}
                                 {{ product.variants.first.weight | divided_by:28.34952 | round: 2 | append: ' oz' }}  
                               {% endcomment %}
                                          
                            </p>
                                  
{% endif %}
```

I tried just fixing it by adding

```
{{ product.variants.first.weight | weight_with_unit }}
```

but that would still round it to 0.2

Any suggestions on what i should write instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

{{ product.variants.first.weight |  times: 1.0  }} g